# Parse JSON Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift

I just upgraded to Swift 2.0 and it looks like there are issues with my `sendRequest` function.

### Swift 1.2 Code (old code):

```
func sendRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completion:(NSData!, NSError!) -> Void) -> () {
    // Create a NSURLSession task
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in
        if error != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                completion(data, error)
            })

            return
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    completion(data, nil)
                } else {
                    var jsonerror:NSError?
                    if let errorDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&jsonerror) as? NSDictionary {
                        let responseError : NSError = NSError(domain: "HTTPHelperError", code: httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo: errorDict as? [NSObject : AnyObject])
                        completion(data, responseError)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    // start the task
    task.resume()
}
```

I made changes for Swift 2.0 and managed to compile without errors. But the data keeps returning `Error Code 400 (bad request)`.

### Current code attempt (Swift 2.0):

This is the current code (compiles, but returns error 400)

```
func sendRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completion:(NSData!, NSError!) -> Void) -> () {
    // Create a NSURLSession task
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                completion(data, error)
            })
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    completion(data, nil)
                } else {

                    do {
                        if let errorDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            let responseError : NSError = NSError(domain: "HTTPHelperError", code: httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo: errorDict as? [NSObject : AnyObject])
                            completion(data, responseError)
                        }
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
                        completion(data, error)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    // start the task
    task.resume()
}
```

Source: I was following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift) but looks like it was written for Swift 1.2

### Edit: This is the `buildRequest` function

```
func buildRequest(path: String!, method: String, authType: HTTPRequestAuthType,
    requestContentType: HTTPRequestContentType = HTTPRequestContentType.HTTPJsonContent, requestBoundary:String = "") -> NSMutableURLRequest {
        // 1. Create the request URL from path
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "\(HTTPHelper.BASE_URL)/\(path)")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

        // Set HTTP request method and Content-Type
        request.HTTPMethod = method

        // 2. Set the correct Content-Type for the HTTP Request. This will be multipart/form-data for photo upload request and application/json for other requests in this app
        switch requestContentType {
        case .HTTPJsonContent:
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        case .HTTPMultipartContent:
            let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(requestBoundary)"
            request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        // 3. Set the correct Authorization header.
        switch authType {
        case .HTTPBasicAuth:
            // Set BASIC authentication header
            let basicAuthString = "\(HTTPHelper.API_AUTH_NAME):\(HTTPHelper.API_AUTH_PASSWORD)"
            let utf8str = basicAuthString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let base64EncodedString = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

            request.addValue("Basic \(base64EncodedString!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        case .HTTPTokenAuth:
            // Retrieve Auth_Token from Keychain
            if let userToken = KeychainAccess.passwordForAccount("Auth_Token", service: "KeyChainService") as String? {
                // Set Authorization header
                request.addValue("Token token=\(userToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            }
        }

        return request
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one :-

```
func sendRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completion:(NSData!, NSError!) -> Void) -> () {
    let request = request
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let error = error
        let response = response
        let data = data
        if  data != nil && error == nil {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!
            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300) {
               do {
                    let jsonData:AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                     print("Success")
               } catch let error as NSError {
                 print("Failed To load")
               } catch {
               // Something else happened.
              // Insert your domain, code, etc. when constructing the error.
              }
          } else {
              print("Connection Error")
          }

    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
  })
   task.resume()
}
```

and also in your buildRequest, use set :-

```
 request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting connection error. Is this a problem with the buildRequest function?

Comment: Updated Answer, have a look :), Yeah most probably there is a some error in your request function

Comment: Found the error in the request function. But your conversion to Swift 2.0 worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Swift 2 it's worth double-checking that your info.plist has an appropriate value for App Transport Security Settings ...

Comment: I don't think thats the issue or I would have gotten something like `App Transport Security has blocked...`, but I added the domain to the plist and still getting 400 status.

Answer (score 0):

instead of saying "if let errorDict... { }

remove the "if" statement and take away the brackets.  So it looks like :

```
 do {

 let errorDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

 let responseError : NSError = NSError(domain: "HTTPHelperError", code: httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo: errorDict as? [NSObject : AnyObject])
                        completion(data, responseError)

 }
 catch {
   //catch code here
  }
```